# Passing product type to Devise sign up page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In my Rails application, when a user goes to the sign up page for my application, I am passing a param with the type of product they are signing up for in the URL. This is based on the link they clicked to get to the sign up page (from the home page or the pricing page). For example,

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up?product=PRODUCT_TYPE
```

The problem is, if the user gets a Devise error (such as email already taken, passwords don't match, etc.) the params are not maintained in the URL.

Is there a way to either a) maintain these params in the URL or b) should I pass the product_type in another way?

Answer (score 1):

You could overwrite sign up function of devise and save it using `session` ? Then if there is no `params['product']` you could get it from `session`. Thats first what came to my mind.

Comment: @Tony M does it answer your question?